# Testcafe cant take screenshot when opening PDF

Tags: pdf, testing, screenshot, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to use TestCafe to open a PDF file from my local directory and then take a screenshot of the PDF File.

But it keeps on giving me the Error

`ERROR The Chrome 68.0.3440 / Windows 10.0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.`

My Code is very simple. Just opening the PDF and then Taking the Screenshot.

```
test('pdfscreenshot', async t => {
    await t
        .navigateTo(`file:///TestCafe/screenshots/picture.pdf`)
        .takeScreenshot('picture.png')
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am able to take screenshots if its not a PDF tho. Ie. If I change it to

```
.navigateTo(`https://www.google.com`)
```

It works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe does not support working with non-Html files (e.g. an image or PDF file ). Nevertheless,  you can create a test that will check status of your file.

For this, obtain file content by the file URL using the [Request module](https://github.com/request/request). You can also use the "[fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)" module if picture.pdf is located in your file system. Then, you can process this content as you need (e.g. check if a file is PDF). The following nodejs module might be helpful for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-pdf-file

If you want to do this in a TestCafe test, create "fixture" without a page:

```
fixture `Check PDF`;
   test('first test', async t => {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yeah you are right I found the issue on their github. https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1471